# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "FOREIGN": syntax error

Tags: sqlite, python-3.4, operationalerror

I am facing an operational error when executing a code at the below given lines of my code.

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customerReg(cname TEXT,cgender TEXT,cphone INT UNIQUE,cusername TEXT UNIQUE,cpassword TEXT UNIQUE)")
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS adminReg(Oname TEXT,Hname TEXT UNIQUE,totalrooms INT,tariff INT,location TEXT,aphone INT,ausername TEXT UNIQUE,apassword TEXT UNIQUE)")
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customerStay(cname TEXT,hostel TEXT,location TEXT,tariff INT)")
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Hostel(FOREIGN KEY(Hostelname) REFERENCE adminReg(Hname),FOREIGN KEY(rent) REFERENCE adminReg(tariff),FOREIGN KEY(roomsavailable) REFERENCE adminReg(totalrooms))")
```

The error which is being displayed is

```
 c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Hostel(FOREIGN KEY(Hostelname)
 REFERENCE adminReg(Hname),FOREIGN KEY(rent) REFERENCE
 adminReg(tariff),FOREIGN KEY(roomsavailable) REFERENCE
 adminReg(totalrooms))") sqlite3.OperationalError: near "FOREIGN":
 syntax error
```

I am not able to see the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This CREATE TABLE statement does not define any columns. (FOREIGN KEY declares a constraint on an existing column; it does not define a new column.)

And REFERENCES is spelled wrong.